# Cannot include <cwindows>

Tags: c++, windows, header-files

```
#include <cwindows>
int main(){}
```

C++ has a feature where the built in .h files can be transformed into the modern C++ equivalent by adding c. Such as stdint.h to cstdint, but for some reason not windows.h to cwindows. Why is this happening?

Comment: Just `#include <windows.h>`, cwindows header doesn't exist, so you can't use it.

Comment: *"C++ has a feature where the built in .h files can be transformed into the modern C++ equivalent by adding c."* - no, C++ does not have such a feature. Perhaps you are getting confused by some library headers such as `stdint.h` and `cstdint`. They are separate headers, not "transformed".

Answer (score 0):

Such feature does not exist. It is the library writers that have to provide `c...` headers because the standard says so. Moreover `windows.h` is not standard C++. It is a windows specific header for windows. How thirdparty vendors name their headers is not mandated by the C++ standard.

Answer (score 0):

The <cwindows> headers dosn't exists.
The headers as <cstdint>, <cstring>, <cmath>, <cstdio> and so on, belong to the C standard language library. The include file <windows.h> belong to the Win32 SDK, under Microsoft license.